# finding width of textView before it is drawn when it is created dynamically

Tags: android

I have an activity that has  imageview1 at the bottom right. After the activity starts and onWindowFocusChanged is called, I want to dynamaically create an textView and place it beside the imageview1 (to the left). I know I can use set the location of textView by modifying its layoutParam but to align it properly I do the following

```
param.setMargins(0, imageView1.getTop(), rootLayout.getWidth()-imageView1.getLeft()-textView.getWidth, 0);
```

. The problem is I can't find out the width of textView because it has not been drawn yet. How can I get around this?

Comment: Did you try with `textView.getMeasuredWidth()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask view to measure itself, but you should specify constrains. For example:

```
final Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("Button");
button.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
Log.d("Test", "measured width: " + button.getMeasuredWidth());
Log.d("Test", "measured height: " + button.getMeasuredHeight());
```

Then you've got:

```
11-09 10:33:14.316 14959-14959/com.madcucumber.testapplication D/Test: measured width: 264
11-09 10:33:14.316 14959-14959/com.madcucumber.testapplication D/Test: measured height: 144
```

Comment: thank you, that looks promising can you explain  View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),

Comment: It's constraint for your view. First argument 0 does not make any meaning, but second arg tells view to be as mush as it wants.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using onSizeChanged will be usefull for you:

> protected void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
>
> Added in API level 1
>   This is called during layout when the size of this view has changed. If you were just added to the view hierarchy, you're called with the old values of 0.
>
> Parameters
>
> w  Current width of this view.
>
> h  Current height of this view.
>
> oldw   Old width of this view.
>
> oldh   Old height of this view.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged(int, int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

You can offcourse use TreeObserver:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = imageView1.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        this.image1.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
        int width  = imageView1.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = imageView1.getMeasuredHeight(); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Yea well thats equivalent to waiting for the view to be drawn, I want it before

Comment: Not really, onSizeChanged() is called after the size was calculated.

Comment: But it is called when view is added to the hierarchy. I want to know the width of the view before  I even add it

Comment: I don't think you can know the dimensions earlier